# Unable to retrieve post values from postman using php

Tags: php, curl, postman

In postman under POST I have added inputs say for ex. from date and to date as in the below format, which am trying to retrieve using PHP. It is working perfectly in my localhost and if I used the same coding in my server it is not fetching any datas.

```
{
    "from_date":"21/03/2019",
    "to_date":"22/03/2019",
}
```

This is code am using:

```
$frmdate='';
$todate='';
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);
$frmdate = $data->from_date; 
echo $frmdate;
$todate = $data->to_date;
echo $todate;
```

I have also tried the curl concept, but didnt get any values so far..

```
$url= 'https://mydomainname/api/customer.php';

$arrContextOptions=array(
      "ssl"=>array(
            "verify_peer"=>false,
            "verify_peer_name"=>false,
        ),
    );  

$response = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
$frmdate='';
$data = json_decode($response);
$frmdate = $data->from_date; 
echo $frmdate;
```

Comment: How was your SSL cert created? Postman will by default not communicate with untrusted SSL certs, but this can be changed in the settings. This is obviously not suited for production.

Comment: Yes, In postman under settings I disabled "SSL certification verification" to off and my ssl certs is trusted